# Number won't increment from within a loop?

Tags: objective-c, loops, increment

Simple program and simple oversight. Generate two random numbers (0-20) and perform math operations on them. Check user's answer. Everything works fine except for keeping track of number of right answers.

Initialized `int correctAnswers = 1` and tried `int correctAnswers` outside of the loop as the placeholder. Correct answers should increment it by one. `++correctAnswers`, `correctAnswers++` and `correctAnswers += 1` all give the exact same answer of 1, regardless how many of the five tries were actually correct.

main.m

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // MathTutor's myMath libraries for creating two random numbers, each between 1 and 20.
        myMath *myMathStuff;
        myMathStuff = [[myMath alloc] init];
        int randomNumberOne = [myMathStuff getRandomNumber];
        int randomNumberTwo = [myMathStuff getRandomNumber];

        // Calculate the expected answers and create a scoring variable.
        float answerMultiplication = (randomNumberOne * randomNumberTwo);
        float answerDivision = (randomNumberOne / randomNumberTwo);
        float answerAddition = (randomNumberOne + randomNumberTwo);
        float answerSubtraction = (randomNumberOne - randomNumberTwo);
        int correctAnswers = 0;

        // Initialize the string and answer variables for scanf().
        char operation;
        float answer;

        // Loop for five iterations.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // Ask what type of operation.
            NSLog(@"Please select an operation: \n M. Multiplication \n D. Division \n A. Addition \n S. Subtraction");
            scanf("%s", &operation);
            // Check for the selected operation.
            switch (operation) {
                case 'M':
                    NSLog(@"What is: (%i x %i)?", randomNumberOne, randomNumberTwo);
                    scanf("%f", &answer);
                    if (answer == answerMultiplication) {
                        NSLog(@"Correct!");
                        ++correctAnswers;
                    }
                    else { NSLog(@"Incorrect! The correct answer is: %f!", answerMultiplication); }
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    NSLog(@"What is: (%i / %i)?", randomNumberOne, randomNumberTwo);
                    scanf("%f", &answer);
                    if (answer == answerDivision) {
                        NSLog(@"Correct!");
                        ++correctAnswers;
                    }
                    else { NSLog(@"Incorrect! The correct answer is: %f!", answerDivision); }
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    NSLog(@"What is: (%i + %i)?", randomNumberOne, randomNumberTwo);
                    scanf("%f", &answer);
                    if (answer == answerAddition) {
                        NSLog(@"Correct!");
                        ++correctAnswers;
                    }
                    else { NSLog(@"Incorrect! The correct answer is: %f!", answerAddition); }
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    NSLog(@"What is: (%i - %i)?", randomNumberOne, randomNumberTwo);
                    scanf("%f", &answer);
                    if (answer == answerSubtraction) {
                        NSLog(@"Correct!");
                        ++correctAnswers;                    }
                    else { NSLog(@"Incorrect! The correct answer is: %f!", answerSubtraction); }
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Sorry, but that is not a valid operation.");
                    // Reduce the loop counter by one to offset the invalid choice.
                    i--;
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Calculate the score percentage and display the score.
        NSLog(@"You correctly answered %i out of 5 questions!", correctAnswers);
        NSLog(@"Your grade for this challenge is %i%%", correctAnswers * 20);
        // Reset the answers counter.
        correctAnswers = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YarGnawh beat me to the correct answer, but to supply fuller detail, this:

```
scanf("%s", &operation);
```

Asks for a full, NULL-terminated string to be deposited at the address of `operation`. So if you enter the letter 'M' then two bytes will be written to that address: the character code for the letter 'M' and then a terminating `NULL`.

That's a buffer overrun because you've declared operation as `char operation;`. So there's only a single byte of storage there. The terminating `NULL` will therefore be written to storage that isn't safe.

In practice it appears to be written to the lowest byte of `correctAnswers`. So that variable gets zeroed. Compilers are free to arrange variables in any order they like so there'd be no reason either to guess that `correctAnswers` would be affected or to be surprised that it is.

So: your code has undefined behaviour. In this specific case that undefined behaviour happens relatively harmlessly to zero out part of one of your other variables.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. The only problem is that %c causes the default: statement of the switch() to be executed.

Comment: With `scanf("%c", &operation)`? It's working correctly with that for me, here.

Answer (score 2):

It problem is in the scanf for operation. Scan for character instead.

```
            scanf(" %c", &operation);
```

Comment: Upped for the speed of response. Rewarded to @Tommy for the explanation. Thank you!

Comment: The problem here is that once %c is used it flags all operations to be invalid (the default: of the switch()).